# create connection string for new database

Tags: asp.net-mvc, connection-string

I have two connection strings. One for my local test machine and one for my production server.  The top one is my current machine and the commented out line is the line for my production server.  Since there is no database yet, do I leave out the password section or do I put in the password I want it to create?

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=helpdesk;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <!--<add name="HelpDesk" connectionString="Server=SQL01;Database=HelpDesk;User Id=;Password=" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />-->
  </connectionStrings>
```

I am using entity code first migrations to create the database, so how would I get it to create the password? or do I need to do that part from within SQL server?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to paste in the connection string. lol I will do that now.

Comment: @teovankot, modified the original question to include the connection string now.

Answer (score 0):

My recommendation would be to just keep it commented out but have the connection string chopped off so that you aren't able to create a connection off of it.

```
add name="HelpDesk" connectionString="... add connection string when required ..."
```

Something like that.  That way if you forget that you need to add data (or in your case, just the password), then you'll throw an exception when trying to create the connection off of this connection string.

In your case, if you just "guess" at the password, there's a chance that's not the user name and/or password you'll use, and then the troubleshooting could get a little trickier with a failed login.

I don't really see the need to have the `HelpDesk` connection string totally populated until that *actual* data source exists (i.e. the database and the credentials to connect to it).

Another thing, there's no need to have your connection strings in your configuration commented out.  Just use preprocessors to determine which connection string should be used depending on if it's a debug build or not:

```
#if DEBUG
            _connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString;
#else
            _connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["HelpDesk"].ConnectionString;
#endif
```

**Edit**: Your connection string should be in there before EF creates it.  EF will create the database and handle that for you.  So there is no real point in omitting that.  As for the `user id` of the connection string, that'll be your login on the SQL Server instance so the credentials are typically stored *outside* of the database.

With that being said, EF will create the database specified by `initial catalog`, and your `user id` and password params will be specific to the **login** on the instance, so you should be able to create that server principal and have the connection string solidified.

Comment: Thomas, thank you for your answer.  However, I think I was unclear.  I am using entity code first migrations - so my project will create the database. I will put that in my original question as well.

Comment: @djblois See my edit.  Still not a problem.  Keep the connection string there uncommented.